# Construct an json for an API endpoint

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I need to pass a JSON object as a query parameter like below.

```
action.setParams({
        'queryParameter': {
                'beginDate' : searchData.get('beginDate'),
                'endDate' : searchData.get('endDate'),
                'planID': searchData.get('planID'),
                'transactionTypeCode' : 'Contribution',
        }
    })
```

I need to add some other properties conditionally, for example.

```
if (some_condition == true)
{
    action.setParams({
            'queryParameter': {
                    'beginDate' : searchData.get('beginDate'),
                    'endDate' : searchData.get('endDate'),
                    'planID': searchData.get('planID'),
                    'transactionTypeCode' : 'Contribution',
                    'newProperty' : newValue
            }
        })
    }
}
```

But, I can not actually sure how to do that. What I have done so far is, create a map for the properties. So my js code looks like

```
var propMap = {
                  'beginDate' : searchData.get('beginDate'),
                  'endDate' : searchData.get('endDate'),
                  'planID': searchData.get('planID'),
                  'transactionTypeCode' : 'Contribution'
              }

if (some_condition == true)
{
    propMap.set('newProperty', 'newValue');
    action.setParams({ 'queryParameter': propMap });
}
```

But, it is not working actually. I need to construct the exact same output as this id the parameter of an API endpoint.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: that's aura component and apex, right? "Not working" on JavaScript side (`console.log(propMap);` doesn't show your new value)? or on server-side (Apex function has such parameter but it's not being passed to it?) How's the function's input defined, as a long list of parameters or as a 1 class object, a kind of wrapper, helper?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this example:

```
var some_condition=true;

var propMap = {
    'beginDate' : 'beginDate',
    'endDate' : 'endDate',
    'planID': 'planID',
    'transactionTypeCode' : 'Contribution'                      
}

if(some_condition ==true)
{
    propMap.newField="my value";
}

console.log(propMap);
```